# Approximate or exact solution of a trigonometric equation

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

How does one determine how close $\theta = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$ is to being an explicit solution of the equation 
$\cos \theta = -\left(\frac{1 + \sqrt{7}}{6 }\right)$?

Comment: Are you asking merely for the existence of $\theta$, or what the exact, actual value of $\theta$ is? I don't think you can get the actual value in this case.

Comment: The existence of some $\theta$ is clear since the value on the right hand side of the equation lies in the range of $\cos(\cdot)$.  Actually I was hoping to find $\theta$ as a fraction of $2\pi$.

Comment: No, unfortunately I do not think that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it's not a rational multiple of $\pi$, so it's likely that the best closed-form answer is $$\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{-1-\sqrt{7}}{6}\right)$$

Comment: I agree and numerical experimentation suggests that one such solution is approximately $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$.  How does one prove or disprove $\theta = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}$ as a possible solution?

Comment: It is pretty close, but the cosines differ by about 0.001. Straightforward calculation might be your best bet?

Comment: If you *really* need to do it with pencil and paper, you can do a Taylor Series for $\cos(\pi/\sqrt{2})$ and a continued fraction for $(-1 - \sqrt{7})/6$ :)